Using GIMP to Achieve Specific Fuzziness Around The Edges
Does anyone know how to achieve the fuzziness effect around the edges of an image as in the example:

I may do this many times, so the simpler the solution the better.
I have blurred out the artist image in the center for copyright reasons.
Thx


Open an image, and create a new layer to use as a background and drag it to the bottom of the layers panel. Fill this with any colour your want.

Add a layer mask to the top image layer. Set it to Black (Full Transparency). And make sure the mask is selected in the layers panel

Choose a large soft edged brush, and set the foreground colour to white. Begin painting to reveal the image.

Set the layer blending mode to "Dissolve". You can continue painting on the mask to reveal more of the image. If you switch the foreground colour to black, you can erase what you painted.




You can also apply a Gaussian blur to the layer mask more if you want to spread the effect out a bit more.



You can take this a step further if you have a specific shape you want to use as a mask. Make sure it's a white shape on a black background, by inverting it if necessary. Then with the mask selected, copy and paste your shape, move it into position, hit the Anchor button. Then apply a Gaussian blur to blur the mask.


There are probably other ways to do this too rather than using the dissolve blend mode, like using some kind of textured/splatter brush with jitter applied to make a mask.

Looks like you got it. It's late and I'm brain-dead. I'll play with this in the morning. Thanks.

Thanks. This worked great. Took me a few seconds to realize I should apply the gaussian blur before using the brush, but that was the secret.

@RKO - if you use a large fuzzy/soft edged brush, you don't actually need to blur anything.
